# MySql subquery access parent left join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t1.`ID`, 
      `notification_type`,
      `notification_by`,
      `notification_by_username`,
      `notification_status`, 
      `notification_date`, 
      `school_key`,
      t1.`class_key`, `post_key`,t2.`class_number` ,t2.`class_section`,t2.`class_subject` FROM `3254534545` t1
      LEFT JOIN `schools_classes.t1.school_key` t2
      ON t2.`class_key`= t1.`class_key` ORDER BY t1.`notification_date` DESC;
```

How can i get the schools_classes.`t1.school_key` value ,, it's the table name .t1.school_key result should be  : 364551436

i get this error

> ## 1146 - Table 'schools_classes.t1.school_key' doesn't exist

Comment: You appear to have t1.school_key in your query , does your query return an error?

Comment: @P.Salmon #1146 - Table 'schools_classes.t1.school_key' doesn't exist

Comment: @SaefMyth . . .  Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited

Comment: You have a table called `3254534545`?

Comment: @SaefMyth: Have you in your DB this table?schools_classes.t1.school_key !? I suppose... No

Comment: @P.Salmon yes i do ,,, it's auto genrated

Comment: the table name is the school_key how can i get the school_key in the outer query ?

Comment: Can you provide sample date as Gordon suggested?